# How to do "SQL: MINUS Operator" in Servicenow?

Tags: servicenow

In ServiceNow, I have 2 queries, A and B.

How could I get C = A - B ?

I know how to do it from sql commands. I want to know how do it in Servicenow ?

Comment: you will need to use database views.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This kind of operation would have to be done in JavaScript in a Script Include.